# Change multiple divs layout from vertical to horizontal

Tags: html, css, center, footer

I am trying to create a footer where there is text to the left, center and right. So far I have done this but the issue is the divs in center are stacking up vertically rather than horizontally. I have tried applying float:left to the .entypo elements which works, but it moves all of them next to .footerslinks-left, instead of staying in the center.

http://jsfiddle.net/8uL2e4bw/

So the HTML is as followed:

```
<footer> 


<div class="topfooter">

<ul class="footerlinks-left">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>



<div class="footeraddress-right">

<p>Address</p>
<p>11 Name Road</p>
<p>TE5 7IN</p>
<p>City</p>
<p>Postcode</p> 

<div class="entypo-phone">01234567890</div>
<div class="entypo-mail">hello@salon.com</div>

</div>

<div class="footersocial-center">
<div class="entypo-facebook-circled"> </div>
<div class="entypo-twitter-circled"> </div>
<div class="entypo-gplus-circled"> </div>
</div>

</div>


</footer>
```

Yes I am aware the code is not the tidiest, I should probably address this first to avoid unnecessary complications!

CSS:

```
footer {

text-align: left;
padding: 10px;
background-color: black;
color: #da82da;
}

.topfooter {

margin: 10px auto;
max-width: 720px;

}


.footerlinks-left, .footerlinks-left a {

float: left;

color: #da82da;
list-style: none;
text-decoration: none;
margin-left: 20px;

}

.footersocial-center {


font-family: 'entypo';
font-size: 30px;
overflow:hidden;
text-align:center;

}



.footeraddress-right {

 float: right;

}

.footeraddress-right p {
margin: 0;
padding: 2px;
}


.entypo-phone, .entypo-mail {

  font-family: 'entypo', sans-serif;
padding: 2px;
}
```

Comment: "... the code is not the tidiest". JSFiddle has a '**Tidy** Up' button...

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I meant more in terms of the elements but it is not bad, the CSS could be made simpler. I've just been lazy so I think I'll work on it next. Actually it's only the .entypo elements that needs to be highlighted differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `display` property for a div is `block`, which expands to 100% width.

Try with:

```
.footersocial-center div {
    display: inline;
}
```

```css
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=entypo);

footer {

text-align: left;
padding: 10px;
background-color: black;
color: #da82da;
}

.topfooter {

margin: 10px auto;
max-width: 720px;

}

.footerlinks-left, .footerlinks-left a {

float: left;
 
color: #da82da;
list-style: none;
text-decoration: none;
margin-left: 20px;

}

.footersocial-center {

font-family: 'entypo';
font-size: 30px;
overflow:hidden;
text-align:center;

}


.footeraddress-right {

 float: right;

}

.footeraddress-right p {
margin: 0;
padding: 2px;
}

.entypo-phone, .entypo-mail {

font-family: 'entypo', sans-serif;
padding: 2px;
    
}

.footersocial-center div{
display: inline;
}
```

```html
<footer> 



<div class="topfooter">

<ul class="footerlinks-left">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>



<div class="footeraddress-right">

<p>Address</p>
<p>11 Name Road</p>
<p>TE5 7IN</p>
<p>City</p>
<p>Postcode</p> 

<div class="entypo-phone">01234567890</div>
<div class="entypo-mail">hello@salon.com</div>

</div>

<div class="footersocial-center">
<div class="entypo-facebook-circled"> </div>
<div class="entypo-twitter-circled"> </div>
<div class="entypo-gplus-circled"> </div>
 </div>

</div>



</footer>
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot Alain1405, that seems to have done the trick! Certainly one I will try and remember for future purposes. Much appreciated..